# Cisco Anywhere VPN - Web Based Installation Was Unsuccessful

Tags: vpn, cisco-vpn-client

I am trying to log in to my work machine from home, but my computer is stuck trying to connect using the Cisco AnyConnect VPN Client. I receive the error message `Web-based installation was unsuccessful` (see attached image). I have tried using Firefox, Chrome, and IE10. I have added my work domain as a trusted site and also the security certificate. I have also uninstalled/reinstalled my Java 7 client but I am still stuck on this screen. Any advice?

**Note**: I am on Windows 7. I am logged in as the only account on my computer (so I assume I am admin).

[image]

Comment: If it's urgent, you may want to contact your support department.  Have you tried running the manual installer as suggested by the error message?

Comment: @dsolimano I have tried running the manual installer. It just restarts my computer, after it completes the installation, but the problem remains. My support department is very backed up today.

Comment: Does it create an icon on the start menu you can click on?

Comment: No, I cannot find one. Perhaps I missed it, what would it be called?

Comment: @dsolimano Nevermind, found it!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Click on the link "Windows Vista/64/XP/2000".  The AnyConnect setup .exe should download - make sure to save it to your Desktop or other place you will remember it.  Then run it, and reboot.

Comment: I ran the AnyConnect setup several times already. When I did so, I selected 'repair'. My other options were 'uninstall', and 'modify'. Should I have selected another option instead?

Comment: Sounds like it's installed.  Look in Start -> All Programs -> Cisco AnyConnect and launch the program.

Comment: Ahh, didn't realize it was a program I had to run. Great, thanks :)